# If I repeat a rxjs.Observable.of(obj), is obj cloned? Why I can't modify it?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex

As I understand, javascript passes objects as reference. So if I call a function with an object as an argument, the function can modify it. I wrote this code:

```
var rxjs = require("rxjs")

var obj = {}

var stream = rxjs.Observable.of(obj).
do((x)=>{x.index=isNaN(x.index)?x.index=0:x.index++; return x}).
repeat(10).
subscribe(console.log);
```

It defines the `index` property on `obj` if it does not exist yet, and increases it if it already exists. Since I'm creating an observable of an object, the observable should be able to modify the obj, right? So I should expect to see the output:

```
{index: 0}
{index: 1}
{index: 2}
...
```

but what happens is that I see

```
{index: 0}
{index: 0}
{index: 0}
...
```

Comment: Also, can shorten the isNaN check to `.do(x => x.index = ++x.index || 0 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not cloned and you can modify it, should you so desire.

Your problem is that the postfix `++` operator returns the previous value, so the value assigned to `x.index` will always be zero. Use the prefix `++` instead:

```
do(x => { x.index = isNaN(x.index) ? x.index = 0 : ++x.index; return x; })
```

Also, the return value from the `next` function passed to `do` is ignored, so the `return` is redundant.

Alternatively, you could use the postfix `++` operator and just drop the assignment to `x.index`:

```
do(x => isNaN(x.index) ? x.index = 0 : x.index++)
```